# Написание виртуального сервера для Apache

Tags: apache

Доброго всем времени суток.

Я web-дизайнер и недавно столкнулся с проблемой написания виртуального сервера. Я создал папку "`site1`" , загрузил туда файл html и хотел уже было уже внести директиву `<VirtualHost>` в файл "`httpd-vhosts.conf`" , но, увы, случилась незадача. Я не нашёл этого файла, хотя в учебном издании написано, что этот файл расположен: `C:\Apache2confextr`a. Я нашёл папку "`conf`", но "`extra`" так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 2):

Если там этого файла нет, можете сделать следующее:

1. Добавить виртуальный хост в файл `httpd.conf` или
2. Создайте сами папку и файл (`extra` и `httpd-vhosts.conf` соответственно). Затем в файле `httpd.conf` добавьте `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь поиском по файлам, этот файл где только не может валяться на самом деле... Причем называться он тоже по разному, но сначала попробуйте его найти по настоящему имени. Если не найдете ищите по словам <VirtualHost> внутри файлов *.conf